# Implementing the interface and joining the interface methods with instance variables

Tags: java, methods, interface

```
public interface Usable {
    public boolean isUsed();
    public void setAsUsed();
    public void setAsNotUsed();
}
```

My question is:
The Book class has to implement the Usable interface and join the interface methods with status instance variable either to set the status of the as used or to set the status of the as not used or to return the current value of used instance variable.

I dont really understand how exactly to do what the question is asking.

Answer (score 1):

Well for a start you will need

```
public class Book implements Usable {
```

and then because you have done this you will need to implement these methods which hint to the need for a boolean field called `used`

```
private boolean used;

public boolean isUsed() {
      return used;
}
```

and hence

```
public void setAsUsed(used = true);
public void setAsNotUsed(used = false);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a class that implements Usable by defining the methods (in your case getters and setters) that are declared there:

```
public class Book implements Usable {

    // Initialization
    private boolean used = false;

    // Getter
    public boolean isUsed() {
        return this.used;
    }

    // Setters
    public void setAsUsed() {
        this.used = true;
    }


    public void setAsNotUsed() {
        this.used = false;
    }

}
```

Comment: OK, how would you call them?

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is your book class:

```
public class Book {
    private boolean used;

    // other things
}
```

To implement the interface, first you need to

```
public class Book implements Usable {
    //...
```

Then, implement the methods one by one. We can guess what each one does by looking at the name and signature. `isUsed` returns a `boolean` so it probably should return whether the book is used. Let's implement this:

```
public boolean isUsed() {
    return used;
}
```

`setAsUsed`, well, set the book as used:

```
public void setAsUsed() {
    used = true;
}
```

And `setAsNotUsed` does what it says on the lid as well:

```
public void setAsNotUsed() {
    used = false;
}
```